# How to link featured image to a page on Wordpress for non-loggedin users in single.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to link featured images of Wordpress to an existing page for non-members (not logged-in users) in single.php (just for posts).

Tried this code but no success:

```
<?php 
    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
        $image = $image[0];
    }
?>
```

So how can I link all of the featured images in posts to one page on Wordpress for non-logged in users (visitors) ? 
Note: This is for all featured images on the site inside posts.

Comment: What is " no success"? Works for every user, even logged in? Shows nothing? Also, does the class `coupons-post` have a `min-height`/`min-width`?

Comment: no need for coupons post changed it

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues with your code first of all, like the `<?php` tag *inside* a `<?php` tag, and the fact you're combing the shorthand echo `<?= $image ?>` and `<?php echo $image; ?>` - You should stick with a single syntax for consistency.

That said, all you have to do is change the link using the [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function. Right now you have the link set to the value of the `$image` (which I've shortened as well).

Now `$link` will be defined as the `$image` URL returned by [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) if the user is logged in, otherwise it will be set to `https://example.com`. Note, this syntax is basically a shorthand "if else" statement called a [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) - handy for simple "one or the other" type variable definitions.

```
<article <?php post_class('col-md-4 site-content'); ?>>
    <?php
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'large' );
        $link  = is_user_logged_in() ? $image : 'https://example.com/';
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">
        <div class="coupons-post" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')"></div>
    </a>
</article>
```

Comment: In which file should I add this? and there is no need for coupons post.

Comment: In `single.php`? I just copied the code you had posted originally and fixed it, so you should theoretically be able to copy/paste it over the code you had originally posted.